# Guice: binding based on another bound value

Tags: java, guice

Suppose I have a class `Environment`, which has sub classes `ServiceA` and `ServiceB`.
**Also in a module I have:**

```
bind(ServiceA.class).annotatedWith(Names.named("Production Service A")).to(...)
bind(ServiceA.class).annotatedWith(Names.named("Test Service A")).to(...)
bind(ServiceB.class).annotatedWith(Names.named("Production Service B")).to(...)
bind(ServiceB.class).annotatedWith(Names.named("Test Service B")).to(...)
```

**Elsewhere, I have something like:**

```
bindConstant().annotatedWith(Names.named("Blessed Service Name")).to(...)
```

What I want to do is, based on the value of the `"Blessed Service Name"` binding (which can take on the names of any of the first set of bindings above), bind an `Environment` annotated with `Names.named("Blessed Service")` to the corresponding bound item.  That is, if `"Blessed Service Name"` was bound to the value `"Production Service A"`, then the two here:

```
@Inject @Named("Blessed Service") Environment blessedService;
@Inject @Named("Production Service A") ServiceA productionA;
```

Would be the same. I'd also like it if the injection worked (up to reasonable extent) if `blessedService` above was `ServiceA` instead of `Environment`.

I've heard that `MapBinder` can do most of what I want, in the sense that with it,

**I can do something like this:**

```
public class BlessedServiceModule extends AbstractModule {
    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        requireBinding(Key.get(String.class, Names.named("Blessed Service Name"));
        requireBinding(Key.get(new TypeLiteral<Map<String, Provider<Environment>>>(){}, Names.named("All Services"));
    }

    @Provides @Named("Blessed Service")
    public Provider<Environment> getBlessedEnvironment(@Named("Blessed Service Name") String serviceName, @Named("All Services") Map<String, Provider<Environment>> environments) {
        return environments.get(serviceName);
    }
}
```

**But what can I do so that**

```
@Inject @Named("Blessed Service") ServiceA blessedService;
```

works in the appropriate circumstances? (i.e. injects `"Production Service A"` normally if it is blessed, and barfs if `"Production Service B"` is blessed)

Answer (score 0):

Why would you inject `ServiceA` or `ServiceB` directly? You know right now that it's unsafe depending on your configuration.

It looks like all you need would be to depend on `@Production Environment` and `@Test Environment`, if you [define your own binding annotations](https://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/BindingAnnotations). Ideally, you should set it up so that *no compiling configuration will barf at run time*, and unless it's critical that the "blessed service name" live in Guice, you can probably refactor that into a switch statement and avoid all sorts of runtime indigestion.

By restricting the visibility of `ServiceA` and `ServiceB`, you can make it impossible to inject the implementations directly, and easy and obvious to inject the concrete implementations whether or not they're blessed. You can also use [requireExplicitBindings](https://google-guice.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/inject/Binder.html#requireExplicitBindings%28%29) to help you keep your code honest about injecting interfaces only.

Comment: What if the type hierarchy was all interfaces instead of classes, avoiding the "directly inject the implementations" issue?  In any event, if the "blessed service name" must remain in Guice, any suggestions?